# Co-authoring when using WorkBook Settings/CustomProperties

Tags: excel, office-js

I've been looking for any documentation which suggests whether there is a way of saving Document Settings & CustomProperties such that they're automatically propagated to co-authors of the current document.

I've done some testing which suggests that's these settings aren't automatically propagated even when the document is saved. I'm also storing XML inside the document so I'm concerned that this won't be propagated as well. Since I'm doing this in Excel, I could always create a hidden sheet to store the properties in and have a watch on the table (or some similar set-up) but this isn't really the avenue I want to go down since some user could easily come along and delete the hidden sheet or manipulate its contents.

Has anyone come across this issue and managed to find a solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Excel JS world.

I have verified this issue, it looks like a co-auth bug in settings and custom properties API. We have created 2 bugs (BUG 4173957 and BUG 4173952) for tracking this issue.

As a workaround, you could use our beta API [worksheet custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcustompropertycollection?view=excel-js-preview), which is in preview, this API support co-auth. You could try it out, please let me know if you have any suggestion on this API. thanks.

Comment: Thank's for looking in to that. My main thoughts are that the documentation is missing some hints that there is a limit of 255 chars when using CustomProperties inside Excel itself (the limit doesn't appear to apply when using Office online). Perhaps there could also be some function to watch custom properties (& CustomXML etc.) for remote changes so we can efficiently caching this info on the client-side?

Comment: I think the bugs are targeting to fix the issue to notify the remote changes. so if this bug fixed, your scenario would be unblocked. 
but before that we would suggest you could try the worksheet custom properties API. you are welcome if you have any feedback on this API.
for 255 chars, yes, i think we should update the document to clarify on this. i will follow up with doc team on this. thanks for your support